# api no se actualiza o muestra datos que ya han sido eliminados

Tags: python, mariadb, flask, nginx, gunicorn

Buen dia, Tengo un problema con una api, tengo una ruta qu elimina los datos de una tabla y tengo otra ruta que consulta los datos de esa tabla. el problema pasa cuando elimino los datos de la tabla al consultar la tabla en la api me sigue mostrando los datos borrados, pero aparecen de manera aleatoria. es decir en ocaciones se muestra bien la consulta pero en la siguiente llamada de la api aparece de nuevo el dato eliminado. aunque en la tabla ya no este ingresado.

```
    @app.route('/aceptar_viaje/<int:id_viaje>', methods=['PUT'])
    def aceptar_viaje(id_viaje):
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Eliminar el registro de viaje pendiente
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM viajes_pendientes WHERE id_viajes = %s", (id_viaje,))

    # Insertar el registro en la tabla 'viajes_aceptados'
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO viajes_aceptados (id_viajes, id_unidad) VALUES (%s, %s)", (id_viaje, 1))

    # Actualizar el estado y notificación en la tabla 'viajes'
    cursor.execute("UPDATE viajes SET estado = 'aceptado', notificacion = 'si' WHERE id_viajes = %s", (id_viaje,))

    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return jsonify({"message": "Viaje aceptado exitosamente"}), 200
```

en esta ruta se elimina el dato de la tabla.

```
@app.route('/viajes_pendientes', methods=['GET'])
def get_viajes_pendientes():
    cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT vp.id_viajes_pe, v.nombre, v.numero, v.direccion, v.destino, v.estado, v.notificacion "
                   "FROM viajes_pendientes vp "
                   "JOIN viajes v ON vp.id_viajes = v.id_viajes")
    viajes_pendientes = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return jsonify(viajes_pendientes)
```

aqui se consultan los datos de la tabla.

Comment: Parece que el problema son los worker de gunicorn , si solo tengo 1 no pasa nada raro en las consultas, pero si tengo mas de 1 ya muestra las inconsistencias en la consulta. saben a que se debe?